# Making post headers links

Tags: feature-request, questions, answers, user-interface

In GitHub, there is a feature where all headers (`<h#>`) have a link attached to them that, when visited, will scroll your screen down to that header on the page.

For example:

[image]

I think this would be a useful feature because, especially on long answers, it helps with directing other users to the section you are trying to mention.

---

This could possibly be extended to lines, where there is a link for each line (also similar to GitHub's file viewer), although this is unlikely.

---

You might say that, "There may be multiple posts with the same headers". A fix for this could be that each header link is given extra information that makes it unique. For example, the post author's ID could be appended to the link.

Comment: Why should a header in a user's post be used to essentially skip other content and answers? Or even just skip parts of your own answer. Surely a single answer is to be read in it's entirely? If not, then it's not a good answer, or needs a TL;DR;. Not sure I see any potential benefits - other than FAQ, where it would be useful.

Comment: @James Sometimes a user may want to point a user to one part of a post.

Comment: And thus "skip" some other part(s) of their post? I'm not sure why that would work in a "Q&A" where the answer is an answer in it's entirety. If just a part of the answer is useful, then just that part should be posted, or it written at the top and underneath "Additionally/side notes...". I'm on the fence a bit, I just can't see any benefits from the arguments you have raised and my (brief) thoughts about it :)

Comment: @James Depending on the conversation between the two users, the entire post may not be relevant.

Comment: The Stack Exchange sites are strictly Q&A. If the "entire post is not relevant" then it is NAA, VLQ, Off-topic, useless, etc.